# Total played time of game in Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, time, timer

I am creating this game on Xcode and I want to keep track of total played time in seconds as the score. But how do I keep the total played time in a variable? Thanks!

Comment: Are you using SpriteKit or UIKit?

Comment: I'm using SpriteKit

Answer (score 3):

The most easy way is to save timestamp of game start using Date() and on game finish call the code like this:

```
let seconds = Date().timeIntervalSinse(startDate)
```

Constant "seconds" will contain number of seconds in Double format.
If you want to check how much time the user spent in the app, the best place for startDate saving is applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) is of your app delegate and for finish date - applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication)

Comment: After getting the seconds you should consider saving the time in the UserDefaults and incrementing it so that you have a "Total time played" value after using the app multiple times.

Comment: My app is called FlyingPig Marathon, and i put applicationDidBecomeActive(_application: FlyingPig Marathon). This gives me an error. What is the correct syntax? I'm using SpriteKit

Comment: What language do you use? Swift or Objective-C?

Comment: I use Swift____

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NSTimer` for this purpose. Create a class variable `totalTime`

```
var totalTime = 0
```

Create a timer

```
let timer: NSTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(tick), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Then you can define your `tick` method as

```
func tick() {
    totalTime += 1
}
```

Don't forget to invalidate your timer when you are finished

Comment: I was trying to invalidate the timer somewhere, but it doesn't work. Should I reassign the var 0 at the beginning of didMove or touchesBegan or something else?

Comment: It depends on where you want the timer to stop. I cannot suggest a place to invalidate a timer since I don't know the workings of the app. If you are having trouble with the syntax, it is `timer.invalidate()`